# Compiling DSC Config that contains Get-NetAdapter in Azure Automation

Tags: powershell, azure, dsc, azure-automation

As seen in the [many Azure Quick Start examples](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=Get-NetAdapter&type=), it is common to use `Get-NetAdapter` to get the Network Interface Name for things like DNS configuration. This is an example:

```
configuration MyConfig
{

    $Interface=Get-NetAdapter|Where Name -Like "Ethernet*"|Select-Object -First 1
    $InterfaceAlias=$($Interface.Name)

    Node localhost
    {
        xDnsServerAddress DnsServerAddress
        {
            Address        = $DNSServer
            InterfaceAlias = $InterfaceAlias
            AddressFamily  = 'IPv4'
        }
   }
}
```

If the command `Get-NetAdapter` is in my configuration and the config is compiled by Azure Automation, I get the following error:

> Cannot connect to CIM server. The specified service does not exist as an installed service.

Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is - its not possible. The configs are compiled on the Azure Automation server, not the target node. Even if I were to find a way to get the network adapter name in the config, it would get the name of the adapter on the DSC pull server, not the target node.

The code in the question will work if you use 1 config per node and you are pre-compiling on the target node then uploading it to Azure Automation.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    xDnsServerAddress DnsServerAddress
    {
        Address        = $DNSServer
        InterfaceAlias = (Get-NetAdapter | ? name -Like "Ethernet*" | select -First 1).Name
        AddressFamily  = 'IPv4'
    }
```

Comment: Good idea, I hadn't tried this. Same error though :(

Comment: in this case I think your only solution is to use script resource :(

Answer (score 0):

Get-NetAdapter internally is using WMI to get the information which doesn't work in Azure Automation. However you can use get-netipinterface cmdlet to get information about the adapter.

Comment: Same problem. I was able to get the Interface Alias locally with `(Get-NetIPInterface -AddressFamily IPv4 -InterfaceAlias Ethernet* | Select-Object -First 1).InterfaceAlias` but this then failed with the original error on Azure Automation.

Comment: Just realized that the scenario you are trying to run will not work with Azure Automation as the DSC configuration is compiled in the cloud and  you need it to be compiled on the node where it has to be applied as you want the output of the adapter to be part of InterfaceAlias.

Comment: Any workaround to get this working with Azure automation and DSC?